# how to load software shop faster on a category

Tags: software-installation

My software shop loads very slow on every category. This happens to everybody or just me?I tried a beter conection but still doesn't load fast

Comment: Same here @QAndrei

Comment: I think this is how it works but i'm not sure

Answer (score 2):

You can install applications by using terminal by using command `sudo apt install (software name)`and its way to faster than that , just google about the required software and find its command to install it. There are other software stores but I don't want to use them.

Alternatively, you can use the synaptic package manager. It is not as colorful as the Snap Store, but it is very fast. Enter this command in a terminal to install it.

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Comment: Thanks Bro @Archisman Panigrahi